# How to read file names from harddisk in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have thousands of photos in my hard-disk. All photo file-names consists of 4 parameter :

```
'7 digit number ' + '-' + '3 digit number ' + '.gif'
```

for instance : `1000091-356.gif`

I'm wondering how to write a  query in order to use `3 digit number` of file name as a paramer for updating my  table which primary key match the `7 digit number` of the file name.

By another word a query which act  like : `update myTable set col2 = 356 where col1=1000091` for all photos .

Comment: What does this have to do with reading file names?  Do you want a query where a parameter is passed in, or is the query supposed to read from file names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting your file names into a table first, (using the script below)

```
CREATE TABLE dirList (
  id int identity(1,1),
  line nvarchar(1000)
)
GO;

INSERT INTO dirList (line) EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir C:\PathToMyPhotos'

SELECT * FROM dirList;
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTRING(line,1,17) [date],
    SUBSTRING(line,18,19) sizeordir,
    SUBSTRING(line,37,100) name
  FROM dirList
  WHERE id > (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM dirList WHERE line LIKE '%<DIR>%..%'
  ) AND id < (SELECT MAX(id) - 2 FROM dirList)
)
SELECT
  id,
  [date],
  isDirectory = CASE WHEN sizeordir LIKE '%<DIR>%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  isFile = CASE WHEN sizeordir LIKE '%<DIR>%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  name
FROM cte
```

Now you can query your filenames using:

```
declare @Lookup varchar(3)
set @Lookup = '123'

select name
from dirList
where isFile = 1 and substring(name, len(name)-7,3) = @Lookup
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to tap into the power of sp_OACreate and the FileSystemObject in order to read filenames from the local machine.

```
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT
```

Here's an article that explains this in full detail.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

---

If all you really need is the filenames, FSO might be too powerful for what you need.  I almost forgot about xp_cmdshell, which is perfect for a little job like "DIR" - see Mangist's answer.

Comment: Could be too much effort for this?

Comment: I think `xp_cmdshell` would be much simpler.